# Getting the cell values of a DataGridCheckBoxColumn from a WPF app in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to step through each line of a datagrid and retrieve the value of the DataGridCheckBoxColoumn but I am struggling to get my code working properly. I am following [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/517789/Get-Cell-Value-of-DataGrid-using-Loop-in-WPF/) webpages example and it works up till line 28 but then on line 29 it throughs a `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` error.

Below I have attempted to add all the code that is relevant, it is not all my code as I don't want to upload it all as its big and some of it is not necessary.

My xaml code.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="modelDataGrid" Margin="30,85,30,60" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="RefDes" Header="Ref Des" Binding="{Binding RefDes}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="RenPartNumber" Header="Renishaw Part Number" Binding="{Binding RenPartNum}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="FileLocation" Header="File Location" Binding="{Binding FileLocation}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="FileStatus" Header="File Status" Binding="{Binding FileStatus}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PartClass" Header="Part Class" Binding="{Binding PartClass}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PartDescription" Header="Part Description" Binding="{Binding PartDescription}"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="IncludeFolder" Header="Include in folder"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

My cs code for when the button to retrieve the values is pressed.

```
private void btnGenerateModel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Make sure you have downloaded the most up to date TFS folder before continuing");

    //Trace.WriteLine(modelDataGrid.Items.Count);

    for (int i = 0; i < modelDataGrid.Items.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = GetCell(i, 6);
        Trace.WriteLine(cell.Content);
    }
}
```

The rest of the cs code copied and updated from the website.

```
public DataGridCell GetCell(int row, int column)
{
    DataGridRow rowData = GetRow(row);

    Trace.WriteLine(row);
    //Trace.WriteLine(rowData.ToString());
    if (rowData != null)
    {
        DataGridCellsPresenter cellPresenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowData);
        DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)cellPresenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
        if (cell == null)
        {
            modelDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(rowData, modelDataGrid.Columns[column]);
            cell = (DataGridCell)cellPresenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
        }
        return cell;
    }
    return null;
}

public DataGridRow GetRow(int index)
{
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)modelDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    
    Trace.WriteLine(row);
    
    if (row == null)
    {
        modelDataGrid.UpdateLayout();
        modelDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(modelDataGrid.Items[index]);
        row = (DataGridRow)modelDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    }
    return row;
}

public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = default(T);
    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T;
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        }
        if (child != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return child;
}
```

Here is the output from the Trace.WriteLine showing the last few lines where the error is thrown.

```
System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox Content: IsChecked:False
System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow
28
System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox Content: IsChecked:False

29
```

It looks like up until line 28 dataRow is a DatGridRow object but onmce it goes to line 29 it doesn't have any data in dataRow, but the DataGrid has about 89 lines in it that it should be returning.
I have been trying to print the contents of dataRow to see why it is coming back null as it shouldn't be, that line in the datagrid has data in it but I am struggling to print the value.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Edit: Just to add it managed to complete and give all the values back correctly a couple of times and now everytime I run it it gives the above error, so not sure why it would wortk sometimes and not others but maybe that will help someone diagnose the fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your code working you need to **switch OFF row virtualization**, it is ON by default:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="modelDataGrid" EnableRowVirtualization="False" Margin="30,85,30,60" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
....
</DataGrid>
```

You get an exception, because `DataGridCellsPresenter` is null for not shown cells. You can see it, if you increase the height of your grid you will stuck by another, higher index.

Better do bind the column to a boolean property in the view model and iterate on demand through the source in the view model.

Comment: This got it working, so simple when you know how, thanks for your help. I am currently learning about MVVVM so hoping to understand it a bit better and move to that implementation type. If you have any links to how to implement the thing I am trying to do in a MVVM way then let me know.